# How to make my square row appear properly

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm new to java and I am trying to make a row of squares using Java that I can use later as a border.
When I run the program the squares appear but either move across the window or disappear.
This is the code below:

```
public int tileSize = 25;
public int row;
public int x = 0, y = 0;
```

---

```
public void draw(Graphics g){
`g.setColor(new Color(38, 127, 0));`
g.fillRect(0, 0, 650, 550);
g.setColor(Color.black);
for(int row = 0; row <= 650; row++) {
     g.drawRect(x, y, tileSize, tileSize);
     row = row + 25;
     x = x + 25;
     y = y + 0;
}
}
```

Comment: where is _g_ come from?

Comment: @LongLuong I think that's the Graphics context.

Comment: Are you sure you want to have 2 definitions of `row`?

Comment: Yea, the g is the graphics, i.e public void draw(Graphics g)

Comment: Fureeish - I've tried different versions of the code given, and this seems to be able to produce the most amount of squares. However, all versions make the squares disappear

Comment: Please 
provide 
a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](/help/mcve)

Comment: Timothy - I've edited the code to show more, I hope this helps

Comment: `y = y + 0` – That's just pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong with your code.

### First of all

When you iterate through your for loop, row get incremented at two different places: at `row = row + 25;` and when the for loops enters its next iteration (by `i++`). That way your row isn't 651 - *because you used `<=` instead of `<`*. I suggest you just get rid of `row = row + 25;`

### Second

You declare your `x` globally and only increment it. That way your row gets shifted each time your Frame gets redrawn. You could declare your `x` locally in the for-loop, or you could set x back to zero after or before the for-loop.

So a solution could be:

```
public int tileSize = 25;
public int y = 0; // y doesn't gets changed
public int x = 0;

g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
for(int row = 0; row < 650; row++) {
    g.drawRect(x, y, tileSize, tileSize);
    x += 25;
}
x = 0;
```